# Fetch _id of a Document in MongoDB 3.3.0 above

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java-3.3.0

Trying to refactor a lot of code from one of our services I ended up using a piece of code as :

```
Document documentObject;
String docMongoId = ((DBObject) documentObject).removeField("_id").toString();
```

which though not on compiling but during execution has resulted into

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.pack.model.Document cannot be cast
>   to com.mongodb.DBObject

wherein `Document` is a type defined by us. We now have a piece of code as follows :

```
MongoCollection<Document> dbCollection = mongoClient.getDatabase("dbName")
                .getCollection("collectionName", Document.class);
```

Seeking help, already went through few links -

[Get ID of last inserted document in a mongoDB w/ Java driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338999/get-id-of-last-inserted-document-in-a-mongodb-w-java-driver)

[MongoError: cannot change _id of a document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031541/mongoerror-cannot-change-id-of-a-document)

[How to query documents using "_id" field in Java mongodb driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9797935/how-to-query-documents-using-id-field-in-java-mongodb-driver)

which mostly suggest using `BasicDBObject` and we don't want to be using the older context anymore. Is there a way I can access the `_id` of the Document now(with client update) in java?

Please do ask for any additional or missing information required here.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to refactor ? Can you add the old code too ? please add an example.

Comment: @Veeram the intent is to keep the _id of a document and preserve it while either updating an existing doc or creating a new doc if there is none matching the search. The _id is also shared in another doc `Client` which basically marks the presence of latest doc.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Let me know if you need me to improve my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to convert from bson type Document to your model Document. Added sample class demonstrating the use.

```
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCursor;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;

public class Mongo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();

        MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("dbName");

        MongoCollection <org.bson.Document> dbCollection = db.getCollection("collectionName", org.bson.Document.class);

        MongoCursor <org.bson.Document> iterator = dbCollection.find().iterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            org.bson.Document inDoc = iterator.next();
            Document outDoc = new Document();
            outDoc.setId(inDoc.getObjectId("_id"));
            outDoc.setName(inDoc.getString("name"));
            System.out.print(outDoc.toString());
        }

    }


    public static class Document {

        private ObjectId id;
        private String name;

        public ObjectId getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(ObjectId id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Document{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
        }

    }
}
```